# Can APP_BASE_HREF wait for promise to resolve

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I need to set a base href property on app bootstrap. everything worked great until we had to add IP checking and set base href based on reponse from ther. 
Here is my service that provides information about basic app configuration based on href:

```
import { Injectable, Injector, Inject, PLATFORM_ID } from "@angular/core";
import { isPlatformServer } from "@angular/common";
import { REQUEST } from "@nguniversal/express-engine/tokens";
import { Http } from "@angular/http";

@Injectable()
export class AppConfigService {
    public config: any = {
        appBaseHref: "",
        country: "",
        currency: ""
    };

    parseURL;
    code;

    constructor(
        private _injector: Injector,
        private http: Http,
        @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object
    ) {
        if (isPlatformServer(this.platformId)) {
            // -> server rendered
            let request = this._injector.get(REQUEST);
            this.parseURL = request.originalUrl.split("/");
            this.code = this.parseURL[1];
        } else {
            this.parseURL = location.href.split("/");
            this.code = this.parseURL[3];
        }
    }

    getAsync() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            if (this.code == "") {
                return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
                    this.http
                    .get("https://ipinfo.io/json?token=xoxoxoxoxox")
                    .map(res => res.json())
                    .subscribe(response => {
                        console.log(response);
                        if (response.country == "PL" || response.country == "pl") {
                            this.config.appBaseHref = "/pl";
                            this.config.country = "PL";
                            this.config.currency = "PLN";
                        } else {
                            this.config.appBaseHref = "/gb";
                            this.config.country = "GB";
                            this.config.currency = "GBP";
                        }
                        resolve(this.config.appBaseHref);
                    });
                })
            } else if (this.code == "pl") {
                this.config.appBaseHref = "/pl";
                this.config.country = "PL";
                this.config.currency = "PLN";
            } else if (this.code == "uae") {
                this.config.appBaseHref = "/gb";
                this.config.country = "GB";
                this.config.currency = "GBP";
            } else {
                this.config.appBaseHref = "/pl";
                this.config.country = "PL";
                this.config.currency = "PLN";
            }
            resolve(this.config.appBaseHref);
        });
    }}
```

I'm using it in app.module like this

```
...
providers: [

    AppConfigService,
    {
        provide: APP_BASE_HREF,
        useFactory: async (config: AppConfigService) => {
            return await config.getAsync();
        },
        deps: [AppConfigService]
    },
...
```

The result is that I get error in console `url.replace is not a function` It looks like this is not waiting till the promise is resoled and is trying to set APP_BASE_HREF earlier.
Am I using the wrong provider - I tried adding APP_INITIALIZER but from my observation APP_BASE_HREF not wait until initializer is resolved as well.
Any help much appreciated

Comment: Can you not do this server side?